# Web 8 Content Management DLL .Net framework version?

Tags: web8, templating, content-manager

While I am trying to build C# template assembly using Web 8 Content Management DLL and .NET framework 4.5, I keep getting "ContentManagement" name space not found error while compiling the application.
Once I change my framework to 4.5.2 the issue resolved.
I didn't get the issue for delivery DLL.
Is Web 8 built on .NET Framework 4.5.2?Is it mandatory to use 4.5.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's built on 4.5.2 and thus it is mandatory to use 4.5.2 or higher.

This is listed on the [Prerequisites for client-side APIs and Web application extensions](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-4C8490C8-2476-4E0D-BF73-F0274E2ED772) page in the documentation, which is part of the broader [Prerequisites for this release](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-7780D1A2-5F52-4A2B-B878-98C119653674) section of the Web 8 documentation.

Comment: No problem. For future reference, we list all of the prerequisites in the documentation. I've updated my answer to provide links to the relevant section.